# Why shouldn't this compile?

Tags: c#, enums

I stumbled upon this weird thing today:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html

Question #5.

The code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    enum Foo
    {
        Bar,
        Baz
    };

    const int One = 1;
    const int Une = 1;

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo f = One - Une;
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

Now according to the answers on http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers-answers.html for question #5

> ... It's a known bug due to some optimisation being done too early, collecting constants of 0 and thinking that any known 0 constant should be convertible to the 0 value of any enum. It's with us now, and unlikely to ever be fixed as it could break some code which is technically illegal but working perfectly well. It's possible that the spec will change instead, of course.

But why?

`One` & `Une` are both const. I.e. they can be calculated compile-time, so it becomes
`Foo f = 0`. And since `0` is a valid value for any `enum`, why shouldn't this compile?

Comment: You are looking for something like this `Foo f` and then `f.Bar= One - Une;` right?

Comment: Because probably the check "is it an constant integral number? If yes, is it 0? then it is ok to implicitly cast it to an enum" is done BEFORE the constant calculations.

Comment: Type safety. Even if your enum is backed by an int, your enum is *not* an int. It represents its own concepts, and as such, assigning an int to an enum is not the correct way to work with it.

Comment: For me the above example compiles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not that the compiler can or cannot make this program work. The problem is: What does the language spec *demand* to be done?

This behavior is a deviation form the spec so it's a compiler bug.

> 6.1.3 Implicit enumeration conversions
>   An implicit enumeration conversion permits the **decimal-integer-literal** 0 to be converted to any enum-type and to any nullable-type whose underlying type is an enum-type.

So it must be a literal. `1-1` is not a literal zero. `0` is literal zero.

I wonder why the spec says "decimal". This means that `hexadecimal-integer-literal` is not included so `0x0` should not work either.

Comment: why it compiles fine in vs 2012 and 2015 ?

Comment: The compiler bug has not been fixed for compatibility reasons. It would break code that previously worked.

Comment: I just learned that there was a buggy C# compiler version which allowed `E e = new DateTime()`! That was fixed however: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2006/03/29/the-root-of-all-evil-part-two/